# Application auto shuts after getting spinner item and calculating

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Whenever i press the button to calculate, the app auto shuts. It is likely due to the spinners(i have a separate app to test the other fields without spinner), is the method of getting the item from spinner and using it in a condition correct? Any help is appreciated!

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{
  EditText height;
  EditText weight;
  EditText age;
  TextView calories;
  Button calculate;
  double h,w,wc,hc,m,wm,z,a,ac;
  Spinner spinner, spinner2;
  String choice;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initControls();
    // Spinner element
   Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

   // Spinner click listener
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

   // Spinner Drop down elements
    List<String> activity = new ArrayList<String>();
    activity.add("Sedentary(little/no)");
    activity.add("Lightly Active(1-3days/week)");
    activity.add("Moderately(3-5days/week)");
    activity.add("Very Active(6-7days/week)");
    activity.add("Extremely Active(Physical Job/2x Training)");

    // Spinner element
  Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

   // Spinner click listener
   spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);       
   // Spinner Drop down elements
    List<String> gender = new ArrayList<String>();
    gender.add("Male");
    gender.add("Female");        
    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> activityAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, activity);
    ArrayAdapter<String> genderAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, gender);
    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    activityAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(activityAdapter);
    spinner2.setAdapter(genderAdapter);}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // On selecting a spinner item
    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    // Showing selected spinner item
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
private void initControls(){
      height=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.height);
      weight=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.weight);
      age=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.age);
      calories=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.calories);
      calculate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.calculate);
      calculate.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
      {public void onClick
      (View  v) { calculate();}});
}
private void calculate(){
      h=Double.parseDouble(height.getText().toString());
      w=Double.parseDouble(weight.getText().toString());
      a=Double.parseDouble(age.getText().toString());
      hc=h*6.25;
      wc=w*10;
      ac=a*5;
      m= wc+hc-ac+5;
      wm=wc+hc-ac-161;
      Log.e("Error","messagehere1");
      String choice = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
      switch(choice){
      case "Sedentary(little/no)":
          if(spinner2.getSelectedItem().equals("Male")){
              z=m*1.2;
              calories.setText(Double.toString(z));
          }
          else{
              z=wm*1.2;
          calories.setText(Double.toString(z));}
      case "Lightly Active(1-3days/week)":
          if(spinner2.getSelectedItem().equals("Male")){
              z=m*1.375;
              calories.setText(Double.toString(z));
          }
          else{
              z=wm*1.375;
          calories.setText(Double.toString(z));}
      case "Moderately(3-5days/week)":
          if(spinner2.getSelectedItem().equals("Male")){
              z=m*1.55;
              calories.setText(Double.toString(z));
          }
          else{
              z=wm*1.55;
          calories.setText(Double.toString(z));} 
      case "Very Active(6-7days/week)":
          if(spinner2.getSelectedItem().equals("Male")){
              z=m*1.725;
              calories.setText(Double.toString(z));
          }
          else{
              z=wm*1.725;
          calories.setText(Double.toString(z));}
      case "Extremely Active(Physical Job/2x Training)":
          if(spinner2.getSelectedItem().equals("Male")){
              z=m*1.9;
              calories.setText(Double.toString(z));
          }
          else{
              z=wm*1.9;
          calories.setText(Double.toString(z));}
          }           
}
```

**Logcat**

```
05-12 10:17:37.339: I/Choreographer(6028): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-12 10:17:37.379: I/PGA(6028): Attempting to create new SOCKET connectionn pid = 6028, tid = 6028
05-12 10:17:37.389: I/PGA(6028): New SOCKET connection: com.example.calories (pid 6028, tid 6028)
05-12 10:19:38.859: E/Error(6276): messagehere1
05-12 10:19:38.859: D/AndroidRuntime(6276): Shutting down VM
05-12 10:19:38.859: W/dalvikvm(6276): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x55e15b20)
05-12 10:19:38.859: I/Process(6276): Sending signal. PID: 6276 SIG: 9
05-12 10:19:38.859: D/AndroidRuntime(6276): procName from cmdline: com.example.calories
05-12 10:19:38.859: E/AndroidRuntime(6276): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.example.calories
05-12 10:19:38.859: D/AndroidRuntime(6276): file written successfully with content: com.example.calories StringBuffer : ;com.example.calories
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these lines

```
// Spinner element
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
// Spinner element
Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
```

with

```
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
```

This will Work.